# Mostrar array en tabla de forma horizontal sin repetir filas

Tags: php, mysql, array, html-tabla

tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "15"
        ["estilo"]=> string(4) "0053"
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "4444444.23"
        ["color"]=> string(5) "verde"
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "23" 
        ["material"]=> string(7) "vacuno" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "130" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(2)
        ["total"]=> string(3) "260" 
   }
   [1]=> array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "16" 
        ["estilo"]=> string(4) "0053" 
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "4444444.25" 
        ["color"]=> string(5) "verde" 
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "25" 
        ["material"]=> string(7) "vacuno" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "130" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(1) 
        ["total"]=> string(3) "130" 
   }
   [2]=> array(9) { 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "10" 
        ["estilo"]=> string(1) "0058" 
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "1232323.23" 
        ["color"]=> string(2) "rojo" 
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "23" 
        ["material"]=> string(2) "sintetico" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "2.8" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(3) 
        ["total"]=> string(3) "8.4" 
    }
}
```

al momento de mostrar este arreglo en una tabla HTML con ayuda de un foreach me genera la tabla pero me muestra 3 filas.
Aquí el detalle es que solamente debo mostrar 2 filas, ya que un estilo se repite, sin embargo debo de mostrar esas dos filas pero cuando el estilo sea igual debo también mostrar el punto de zapato que compro. Algo similar a esto, lo hice en excel la forma en como debería de quedar la tabla en html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde descripción sea solamente el estilo, y si hay mas de un punto de un estilo igual que se vaya agregando en su respectiva celda de punto del zapato.

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos, se los agradecería mucho amigos.

Comment: Aclárame si lo he entendido bien. Quieres pasar ese array a una tabla, y que en esa tabla se vayan sumando si es que tienen el mismo estilo de zapato, pero diferente o igual tallaje

Comment: @matahombres así es amigo, osea ese array para que mejor me entiendas es una venta donde los productos son zapatos y se manejan tallas, entonces esa venta se tiene que mostrar en una tabla pero omitiendo estilos iguales PERO NO omitiendo sus respectivos puntos o tallas que adquirio, por eso puse la foto, si es el estilo 0053 tiene que ver una fila y en esa fila se tiene que mostrar cuantas unidades de stock compro en su respectiva columna del tallaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo solucionado amigos, gracias.

```
foreach($array85 as $el){
$keys = ['stock_vendido', 'punto'];
$size = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);



if (!isset($report[$el['estilo']])) {
  $shoe = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return !in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
  unset($shoe['total']);
  $report[$el['estilo']] = $shoe;
  $report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'] = [];
} 
$report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'][$size['punto']] = $size['stock_vendido'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución fácil de entender sería generar otro array que se identifique por estilos y que vaya sumando el tipo de tallaje diferente.

**Generar nuevo array**

```
<?php
$datos=(tu array);
$array_tallajes=array();
foreach($datos as $item){
    $value=$item["estilo"]."-".$item["material"]."-".$item["color"];
    $punto=$item["punto"];
    $precio=$item["precio"];
    if(!(array_key_exists("precio_total",$array_tallajes))){
        $array_tallajes["precio_total"]=0;
    }
    $array_tallajes[$value]["precio_total"]+=$precio;
    if(array_key_exists($value,$array_tallajes)){
        if(array_key_exists($punto,$array_tallajes[$value])){
            $array_tallajes[$value][$punto]+=1;
        }else{
            $array_tallajes[$value][$punto]=1;
        }
    }else{
        $array_tallajes[$value]=[$punto=>1];
    }
}
print_r($array_tallajes);
//Output: Array ( [0053-vacuno-verde] => Array ( [23] => 1 [25] => 1 ) [0058-sintetico-rojo] => Array ( [23] => 1 ) )
?>
```

**Tabla ejemplo**

```
<?php
foreach($array_tallajes as $estilo){
    <td>if(array_key_exists($estilo,$estilo[23]){echo $estilo[23]}</td>
}
?>
```

Lo más importante de este código es el `array_key_exists` que checkea si existe esa clave en el array (ejemplo: `$my_array['testeo']` donde 'testeo' es la clave). Si existe la clave suma el contenido existente, si no existe lo crea y le asigna el valor a 1

Comment: Hola nuevamente amigo @matahombres , la parte de arriba funciona perfecto, solamente que al tratar de mostrar la información no me sale, como puedo hacerle para que la tabla quede como la NUEVA imagen que publique en la pregunta, la hice en excel en la forma que debe quedar.

Comment: amigo @matahombres ya lo verifique nuevamente y sigue sin darme, de hecho lo que me arroja al segundo array generado es esto: array(2) { ["0053-de vaca-verde"]=> array(2) { [23]=> int(1) [25]=> int(1) } ["k-jj-jj"]=> array(1) { [23]=> int(1) } } 
lo cual es incorrecto porque ya cambie el array, le modifique las cantidades vendidas de stock y no me lo da, alguna otra forma de solucionarlo? y que quede tal como en la imagen que subi aqui

Comment: Precio total ya lo tienes. Pero el precio unitario no se a lo que te refieres, si me lo puedes explicar edito la pregunta de nuevo...